# How to get date converter XML data?

Tags: java, spring

I want to converter date.

dutyTime1c of output data "2000".

how to can do converter output "20:00" or "pm. 20:00"?

**XML parsing data**

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:{
                        String tag = parser.getName();
                        switch(tag){
                        case "item":
                            hospital = new HospitalVO();
                            break;

                        case "dutyTime1c":
                            if(hospital != null)
                                hospital.setDutyTime1c(parser.nextText());
                            break;
```

Comment: Try doing some **research**, e.g. Google [`java format time`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+format+time), or maybe [`java parse time`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+parse+time) since your code seems to read *input*, not generate *output*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for.  It converts the time from a string of format "2000" to either of the formats you suggested.

```
String oldTime = "2000"; // replace with parser.nextText();

Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").parse(oldTime);

String newTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
String newTime2 = new SimpleDateFormat("a. HH:mm").format(date);

System.out.println(newTime);
System.out.println(newTime2);

//hospital.setDutyTime1c(newTime)
//or
//hospital.setDutyTime1c(newTime2);
```

This prints:

```
20:00
PM. 20:00
```